# using 'email' values of an array for mail() PHP

Tags: php, arrays, email

My array named $array is like:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2459
        [email] => example1@yahoo.com
        [action] => waiting
        [udid] => 1232123212321232123212321232123234523452
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2462
        [email] => example2@yahoo.com
        [action] => waiting
        [udid] => b851125907768199c03ab24887fdfea96e3183a6
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2463
        [email] => example3@yahoo.com
        [action] => waiting
        [udid] => f7ddf0b4596ea5d6c23fad0ab0f8f92a61f2103d
    )

)
```

So what I'm looking for is a string like:

$emails= "example1@yahoo.com,example2@yahoo.com,example3@yahoo.com"

to use is mail()

```
mail($emails, "Confirmation Email", $body, $headers);
```

However I can use file_put_content & file_get_content to store and retrieve the values, I'm looking for a short, better and professional way!

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: You're probably looking the the [array_column](http://php.net/array_column) function. (Click the link)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using PHP5.4 and array_column is not supported in this version!

Comment: I know that its the not what you asked but, you should consider upgrading your php version since 5.4 has no more support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your array into that string using the `array_column` and `implode` functions.

```
<?php

$values = [
    ['id' => 1, 'email' => 'email1@gmail.com'],
    ['id' => 2, 'email' => 'email2@gmail.com'],
    ['id' => 3, 'email' => 'email3@gmail.com'],
    ['id' => 4, 'email' => 'email4@gmail.com'],
];

$emails = implode(',', array_column($values, 'email'));

echo $emails;
```

Comment: array_column is the hash.pluck of php? hmmm

Comment: Don't know what hash.pluck means.

Comment: `pluck` method of Hash objects in Ruby :P

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
$emails = array();
foreach ($input_array as $rec) {
    $emails[] = $rec['email'];
}
$emails = implode(',', $emails);
```

Comment: I was looking for something like what William Okano suggested(without loop) but it's not compatible with PHP5.4. Thanks anyway

Comment: I tend to lean towards implementation which will run just about anywhere, but otherwise I agree `array_column()` would be the best option.